# Segmentation fault (core dumped) over a 100 round loop bash script

Tags: linux, bash, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, coredump

I know there are a lot of questions on that famous "Segmentation fault core dump", but for what I can see, C/C++ is involved in most of them. But my issue is specific to a bash script, so I am trying my luck here.

I am running a simulator script (400+ lines so I cannot show you the code, can I ?) which sets and calculates a fight between two characters using dices and a profile (like you would do in a Dungeons and Dragons tabletop RPG). I have a reinitialisation function to reset the fight from scratch so that it can start a new one when there is a winner. At the end of the X rounds, some values from it are displayed (% hit, %block %hp per round, etc).

If I set 1, 50 or 100 rounds (100 fights), it's okay, it runs perfectly. But over 130~ fights, all of sudden, it displays without any lag or other complications the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" message.

I have a general idea of what it is, but I cannot explain why it happens, I cannot resolve it, and I do not know what to do, or what to look for.

Some notes I can say after browsing a lot of topics :

There is no import, no based command system, no sed, awk, no array, no "complicated" command. I am just playing with variables (integer). No string. The most "complexe" command (to get a random number) is probably

```
(echo $((1 + RANDOM % 20)))
```

All my conditions are like this

```
if [[ "$Skill_Block2" == "Yes" ]];
then
```

With double bracket and variable between double quote (forgetting double quoted variable inside conditions could lead to problem, I heard).

There is no && or || or -a or -o (I also read that using direct "if" statement would be better)

The whole script is built around functions (easier to modify / implement). A function to calculate the damage is called by a function which check if a character can dodge the successful attack, which has been landed by another function allowing the success or the failure of that attack. Etc. I don't know if it is a good way of developping, but it "worked" so far.

I have accents and French characters, but they seem to be well managed by my OS version (Ubuntu).

I echo pretty much every single resolution so I can track mistakes. Perhaps displaying so much text is eating my virtual memory ? But I would never expect that on a Linux, to be honest.

I don't think I have infinite loops since I can run it 50++ times without any problem in the exact same order.

To display the stats, I am using a dirty way (I think) :

```
touch statistique.txt
    echo "#|Player 1|Player 2" > statistique.txt
    echo "ATT OK|$Number_Touch_OK1|$Number_Touch_OK1" >> statistique.txt
    echo "ATT Failed|$Number_Hit_Failed1|$Number_Hit_Failed2" >> statistique.txt
    echo "DEF Tried |$Number_Dodge_Tried1|$Number_Dodge_Tried2" >> statistique.txt
    [...]
    echo "Victory Number|$Victory1|$Victory2" >> statistique.txt
    echo " "
    column statistique.txt -t -s "|"
```

I tought about EOF, but I was not sure the variables would be interpreted. But at least I have a nicely formated text.

My Ubuntu is run on my Windows. Might be the problem ?

---

So here I am. I feel confused, and I am not very enthusiastic about posting this message as a wall of text without any code because it's too long (but if someone is brave enough, I can share the code, no problem). 
I have seen too few message about memory leak on bash, so... I cannot imagine a Linux OS running out of memory  If you have any idea, advice, software (I tried Valgrind, but again, I am not sure it works with a bash script), please let me know.

EDIT : here's the file (solveur.sh) :
https://github.com/IlliciteS/script

Comment: does your script have a `shebang`? e.g. `#!/bin/bash` at the top

Comment: Yes it has :#!/bin/bash

Comment: Perhaps [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) would be able to find the error, if its some syntax error thats causing that. Else, I don't think we can really help unless you post the whole script somewhere.

Comment: First thing it comes to mind is calling some external command like "sort", "yes", among others. Second thing is to check whether you have a recursive function that can cause this behavior. Third thing is to debug with echo's to find the exact iteration and the exact line of the script is triggering the seg fault. Forth, maybe it would be useful if you post your script in GitHub and link it here.

Comment: You could put the code on gist.github.com or upload it to a temporary file holding site and link to it.

Comment: Does `set -x` give any information at least what command it is trying to execute when it segfaults?

Comment: Did not know about Shellcheck. I am looking at it right know, thanks for that, it's helping me right now.
And I have just created a Git (1st time, did not know it was that simple and free. :) )
Hope it works.

Comment: I have just tried set -x, running the script 4 times. The segfault never happens at the same time. Looks like it's random.

Comment: One thing you can do to help debug and reduce randomness is assign a value to `RANDOM` to seed the random number generator; this should make the seg fault occurrence deterministic. For example, initializing with 100 make the seg fault appear at `Reinitialisation_Carac_New_Round`, it seems.

Comment: If you put a `declare -p` somewhere in your loop, you'll see that the call stack grows (the `FUNCNAME` array); I see more than 5,800 calls. It looks like you recurse somewhere.

Comment: Yep, your functions `Test_Esquive1`, `Degat_Parade1` etc. never return, they all call another function before returning.

Comment: I will definitely learn more about `declare -p`. Now I can indeed see the `FUNCNAME`, `BASH_LINENO` and `BASH_SOURCE` going mad. How did you know, then, it was about `Test_Esquive1` and `Degat_Parade1` ? (And I wonder if there is not a third function since I see 3 names)

Comment: It's not these two functions specifically, it's all of them. Here's is an excerpt from the call stack: `[2]="Touch1" [3]="Touch2" [4]="Touch1" [5]="Touch2" [6]="Touch1" [7]="Touch2" [8]="Touch1" [9]="Touch2" [10]="PV_Par_Restant2" [11]="Degat_Parade1" [12
]="Test_Parade2" [13]="Touch1" [14]="Touch2" [15]="PV_Restant2" [16]="Degat_Flat1" [17]="Test_Parade2" [18]="Touch1" [19]="Touch2" [20]="Touch1" [21]="Touch2" [22]="Who_start_fight"` No function ever finishes, you always call another function first.

Comment: I was wondering in my main post if calling functions over functions was ok. I guess not. Pitty, it was really handful and easy to manage... Except for memory problem. :D And I guess there is no way of closing all the previous opened functions when I reach the final function just before reinitialising a new fight. I'm gonna rewrite the whole thing.
Anyway, thank you a lot for your help ! You may want to make an official reply, I would definitively flag it as a "green answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your program recurses endlessly. As each level of recursion consumes more memory, bash runs into the segmentation fault. Here's a minimal script to reproduce the problem (wrapped inside `bash -c` so that your interactive shell doesn't crash):

```
$ bash -c 'f() { f; }; f'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

You can prevent the segfault by limiting the maximum recursion level using bash's `FUNCNEST` variable. However, this will only abort a bit more gracefully. To solve the actual problem you have to rewrite your script.

To identify the problem, You can look at the call graph of your script:

[image: call graph, generated using <code>{ fNames=$(grep -Po '^\w+(?=\(\))' solveur.sh); echo "digraph callgraph {"; tr \\n \\r < solveur.sh | grep -Po '\r\K\w+\(\).*?\r\}' | while read -r f; do; f=${f//$'\r'/$'\n'}; fName=$(echo "$f" | grep -Pom1 '\w+'); echo "$fName"; echo "$f" | tail -n+2 | grep -Fwof <(echo "$fNames") | sed "s/^/$fName -> /"; done; echo "}"; } > callgraph.dot;</code> and may not be 100% accurate]

Every cycle inside this graph could max out the call stack. A bit of recursion is ok. But for your task, loops seem to be more natural anyway. I would start by using a loop to start new fights. Delete `Relance_Match()` and change your main "method" to

```
for ((i=0; i<Nombre_Match_Total; i++)); do
  Who_start_fight
  echo "..."
  Reinitialisation_Carac_New_Match
done
echo "..."
Statistique
```

#### Further Improvments Unrelated To Recursion

You can drastically simplify your script with arrays. Right now, each player has its own set of variables and code fragments, e.g

```
# for player one
Victoire1=0
Touch1() {
  # lots of code using <insertThingHere>1, e.g.
  ((Victoire1++))
}

# for player two
Victoire2=0
Touch2() {
  # the same code as in Touch1, but with <insertThingHere>2 instead, e.g.
  ((Victoire2++))
}
```

With arrays this could be simplified to

```
Victoire=(0 0)
Touch() {
  player=$1
  # lots of code using <insertThingHere>[player], e.g.
  ((Victoire[player]++));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I have thought about running the same function for both of the players (I've started that 1 year ago with python but I got stuck), but I did not feel confortable right now trying to reverse them again and again. Might be harder to track and fix mistakes(?).
I've done what you say and it works, except for one very weird behavior of my Victory_Condition. I've updated my script on GIT, posted the weird output in a new file (line 39) and explain what's strange, if it's not too much asking...

Comment: Seems like you have to eliminate more recursion, probably that one between `Touch1` and `Touch2`. Instead of calling them from each other, let them return and use a referee to end the game. Something like `while Touch1 && IsAlive2 && Touch2 && IsAlive1; do :; done`. You can see the recursion levels with `set -x` if you set `PS4='+ Ln$LINENO ${FUNCNAME[*]}: '`.

Comment: Personally, I would rewrite the script from scratch. However, I already know *how* I would structure the new program. If you don't know what you should change, then a complete rewrite might not improve things and only add more work. Some pointers: **1.** Use loops **2.** Exit functions once they did their work (e.g. `Touch1` should terminate after the attack and *not* execute `Touch2` too) **3.** Use arrays (instead of `var1/2`) and function parameters (instead of `func1/2`). I think that would make it easier to track down problems as the script gets shorter and less redundant.

Comment: You're right, I really needed to rewrite it. Which I've done. I used arrays, I think. Like P1=0 P2=1, then ATT[0] ATT[1] and so on. So I could use a single function for each action instead of two by using a Reverse function to swap between Attacker=0 and Defender=1. Lastly, 3 while loops, and I made sure no function is calling another one. And I managed to make it work, actually ! What surprises me the most is how fast it runs compared to my old script. I woulda never expected such a big diff on such a little script. 2000 simlations work like a charm. 
Thank you very much for your help. :)